# Search through an array for a specific number

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I am completely baffled on how to do what seems like such a simple procedure. I have an array I need to search through to find a specific user inputted number within the array and count its occurrences. Every single alteration I try to my code gives me the same result. Every run my JE conditional hits as if the two compared values are equal when I'm deliberately setting the array values so I should only get a specific number of hits.

```
    mov esi, myArray
    mov ecx, sizeOf
    mov eax, delim

L3:
    cmp eax, [edi]
    JE FOUND

FOUND:
    inc count
    add edi, TYPE DWORD
    loop L3
```

Debugger isn't helping me either, I'm either missing something or it's not showing me what I need to see. My eax value is fine but the edi value is a 7 digit number

Comment: Think about what happens when `JE FOUND` is taken vs. when it falls through.  Both ways go to the same place because you put the `found` label in the wrong place.  You want to jump *over* an `inc` instruction with `jne`.

Comment: Also, your code doesn't set EDI, only ESI.  And since this is MASM, you're loading ESI with the first element of the array, not a pointer.